# Split up words in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've created a way to take a string in MS SQL and break it up at a space to avoid word splitting. This splits a string up into 3 separate strings for new lines if each line is 17 characters or greater.

```
DECLARE @Prod_Desc varchar(50) = '12345 BAG 15 LB NR SML BTS CHICKEN MEAL AND RICE'
DECLARE @Prod_Desc_Line2 varchar(50);
DECLARE @Prod_Desc_Line3 varchar(50);

-- Generate second line and center
IF len(@Prod_Desc) >= 17
BEGIN
SELECT @Prod_Desc_Line2 = SUBSTRING(@Prod_Desc, 18 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Prod_Desc, 1, 17)), 1), len(@Prod_Desc) + CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Prod_Desc, 1, 17)), 1) - 17);
SELECT @Prod_Desc = SUBSTRING(@Prod_Desc, 1, 17 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Prod_Desc, 1, 17)), 1));
END;

-- Generate third line and center
IF len(@Prod_Desc_Line2) >= 17
BEGIN
SELECT @Prod_Desc_Line3 = SUBSTRING(@Prod_Desc_Line2, 18 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Prod_Desc_Line2, 1, 17)), 1), len(@Prod_Desc_Line2) + CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Prod_Desc_Line2, 1, 17)), 1) - 17);
SELECT @Prod_Desc_Line2 = SUBSTRING(@Prod_Desc_Line2, 1, 17 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Prod_Desc_Line2, 1, 17)), 1));
END;

PRINT(@Prod_Desc);
PRINT(@Prod_Desc_Line2);
PRINT(@Prod_Desc_Line3);
```

Output:

```
12345 BAG 15 LB
NR SML BTS
CHICKEN MEAL AND RICE
```

It works how I want it , but I think it looks sloppy. I was wondering if there was a better way to do this string division or if a function exists to do so?

For clarification, if a string is greater than 17 characters, it finds the last space before that limit is hit, truncates it off of the original string, and adds it to the next string for the next line.

Comment: This would be better posted on codereview.  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are many other ways to do this -- this question is way to broad for stackoverflow

Comment: what happens when that last line is 7500 characters? You'd want it super long? Also, are you trying to apply this to a set of data? If so, then i'm guessing you have a loop somewhere based off your current logic. Is this true?

Comment: The full sql procedure generates a .DPL for a printer, so it is only getting information from one item for one label. The maximum a given string can be is 50 characters, which comes to an average of 16.67 characters per line, so that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option

**Example**

```
DECLARE @S varchar(100) = '12345 BAG 15 LB NR SML BTS CHICKEN MEAL AND RICE'
Declare @MaxLen int = 17

Select Line1 
      ,Line2 = ltrim(stuff(Line2,1,len(Line1),''))
      ,Line3 = ltrim(stuff(Line3,1,len(Line2),''))
 From (
        Select Line1 = Left(@S,@MaxLen-CharIndex(' ',Reverse(Left(@S,@MaxLen))))
              ,Line2 = Left(@S,@MaxLen*2-CharIndex(' ',Reverse(Left(@S,@MaxLen*2))))
              ,Line3 = @S
      ) A
```

**Returns**

```
Line1              Line2        Line3
12345 BAG 15 LB    NR SML BTS   CHICKEN MEAL AND RICE
```

> **EDIT a Set Approach**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'12345 BAG 15 LB NR SML BTS CHICKEN MEAL AND RICE') 
,(2,'Some Random Text should be split into 3 strings') 

Declare @MaxLen int = 18  --<< Changed to 18

    Select A.ID
          ,Line1
          ,Line2 = ltrim(stuff(Line2,1,len(Line1),''))
          ,Line3 = ltrim(stuff(Line3,1,len(Line2),''))
     From  @YourTable A
     Cross Apply (
                    Select Line1 = Left(SomeCol,@MaxLen-CharIndex(' ',Reverse(Left(SomeCol,@MaxLen))))
                          ,Line2 = Left(SomeCol,@MaxLen*2-CharIndex(' ',Reverse(Left(SomeCol,@MaxLen*2))))
                          ,Line3 = SomeCol
                 ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Line1               Line2                  Line3
1   12345 BAG 15 LB     NR SML BTS CHICKEN     MEAL AND RICE
2   Some Random Text    should be split        into 3 strings
```

Comment: 1 from me since it can be applied set wide, which i don't *think* the OP logic  would.